# Firebase - get user based on date

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a `User` model which contain a field:

```
var created_on: Double?
```

and when the user signs up it gets assigned:

```
Date().timeIntervalSince1970
```

and i want to get the users who joined today, at the moment i have something like:

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("users")
      .whereField("activated", isEqualTo: 1)
      .whereField("city", isEqualTo: loggedInUser.city)
      .getDocuments{(snapshot, error) in
      guard let snap = snapshot else {
          return
      }
```

Im trying to have something like this (pseudo):

```
.whereField("created_on", isEqualTo: today)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you storing timestamp, your query actually is selecting a range:

```
.whereField("created_on", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: startOfToday)
.whereField("created_on", isLessThan: startOfTomorrow)
```

Where `startOfToday` and `startOfTomorrow` are the `TimeInterval`/`Double` values for the start of today and tomorrow respectively.